# How do I reset Byobu's settings?

Tags: server, byobu

Right problem is I want use Byobu I really like it BUT I messed up and changed settings in F9 and choose the screen keybindings NOW I cant get back to the F9 settings to change it back and cant use any the F keys for Byobu, its very annoying and cant find a solution anyone care to help with the matter?

I tried remove Byobu and screen without any difference made I hunted online cant find an answer either

I'm running ubuntu server 10.4

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

- Delete your `~/.byobu` folder.
  This folder contains most of your keybindings, and config settings.
- You can also launch `byoby-config` and change your configuration there (It does not allow changing screenbindings, only notification panel). This is the same binary which is launched on pressing F9
- Lastly try reinstalling with a purge (`apt-get purge byobu`) and install it again (`apt-get install byobu`)

Comment: you my friend are a superstar i been scratching my head for hours n hours with this the only thing i didnt do was Delete the  ~/.byobu folder.    then reinstalled thank u soo much for ur help saved me lots hassle .

Comment: [As any app should](https://askubuntu.com/a/829683/349837), on newer installations you will find Byobu's settings dir (`$BYOBU_CONFIG_DIR`) on `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/byobu` ([by default](https://superuser.com/a/425712/500826) `$HOME/.config`) instead of the old `$HOME/.byobu` ([bug 1315204](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/1315204)). See also [`xdg-user-dirs-update`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/xdg-user-dirs-update.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Delete `/tmp/tmux-[UID]` folder (where `[UID]` is your user id).
- Delete  `~/.tmux.config`

Byobu uses tmux as its backend by default so the way it behaves might depend on tmux configuration. Even though `tmux ls` shows no sessions removing the `/tmp/tmux-[UID]` might help.